# Firebase Messaging works, but Analytics does not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have empty analytics in firebase dashboard.

Firebase Messaging is working fine though.

This is my dependency :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

Google Services plugin is also added in the Module level build gradle file like this :

```
   plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    }
```

Project Build Gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}
```

Now, In my MainAcitivty, I have initalzied it like. ( No explicit firebaseApp initialization because that is setup automatically by google services json file )

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity))
        setContentView(binding.root)

        firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
        firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)

}
```

What would be the workaround for this?

I tried with kotlin way of initialization as stated in docs too, which is again not working --> Firebase.analytics